# jQuery.each() undefined issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code

```
function myFunction(items) {
   // this prints out 11
   alert(items.length);

   $(items).each(function(i, item) {
       // item is undefined for some reason
   }
}
```

It I alert the length of items, it has elements in it (11 to be exact). so how could 11 items be present, but jQuery still pass undefined?

Comment: What's the value of `$(this)` inside of your `.each()` callback? Nothing looks incorrect so it would be helpful to see an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: What is the type of `items`? is it an array or an array-like object like an `HTMLCollection` returned from `.getElementsByClassName()` for instance. Either way why not just use a standard for loop?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The only explanation for this is the that items array contains values which are undefined, i.e :

```
items = [undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined];
```

Both of the other answers are wholly incorrect. The first parameter of `each` is the index, not the value, and jQuery.fn.each calls jQuery.each. There is no disambiguation between them.

Comment: Matt you are right. It was my code that made the mistake. I was using JSLINQ and I wrote my own implementation of Take(n). I was adding undefined objects to my array by mistake through a logic bug.

Comment: Old implementation is

Take: function(count) {
            var retVal = new Array();
            for (var index = 0; index < count; index++)
                retVal[retVal.length] = this.items[index];
            return new JSLINQ(retVal);
        }

Comment: New one is

Take: function(count) {
            var retVal = new Array();
            for (var index = 0; index < Math.min(count, this.items.length); index++)
                retVal[retVal.length] = this.items[index];
            return new JSLINQ(retVal);
        }

Answer (score 5):

It sounds like you are **not** passing a `jQuery wrappet set` to your function. If you pass
an `array` or an `object` you need to use the `jQuery helper function` **$.each()** like

```
$.each(items, function(index, element){
});
```

As I already mentioned several times in other answers, it is bad practice to loop over an array with `.each()` or javascripts native `for..in`.

If you are passing `arrays` use a standard `for loop`.

**edit**

As it turns out, you actually really can call the `jQuery constructor` with a standard array.
But it seems like terrible karma to do so, you can't call 95% of all those jQuery methods, unless you want to crash / corrupt your code.

Comment: jAndy - An array will actually work the way OP has it (though I would agree that `$.each()` is better and `for loop` is best).

Comment: @patrick: Doh I wasn't exactly aware of that. What happens if you pass a standard array to the jQuery constructor and call like `.animate()` or whatoever on it?

Comment: jAndy - Seems to be catastrophic failure (unless of course it was an array of DOM elements). A good reason to not do it. But then again, when you think about it, that is what jQuery's `.map()` does. The callback returns some arbitrary value, which is placed into a jQuery object.

Comment: Animate will work against anything. For example:

var foo = {
    x: 10,
    y: 12
};

$(foo).animate({ x: "+=20", y: "20" }, 1000, function () {
    alert(foo.x + ":" + foo.y);
});

Will spit out "30:20". Is this useful? Perhaps not in everyday work.  :)

The trick with arrays is you'll set the same value across each entry. Example:


var foo = [{ x: 10 }, { x: 20}];

$(foo).animate({ x: "+=30" }, 1000, function () {
    alert(this.x);
});

Spits out "40" and "50".

Answer (score 0):

Since comments don't allow pretty code listings ... (do they?):

Animate will work against anything. It's documented as only working against CSS properties, but just to prove a point:

```
var foo = { x: 10, y: 12 }; 

$(foo).animate({ x: "+=20", y: "20" }, 1000, 
      function () { alert(foo.x + ":" + foo.y); });
```

Will spit out "30:20". Is this useful? Perhaps not in everyday work. :)

The trick with arrays is you'll set the same property across each entry. Example:

```
var foo = [{ x: 10 }, { x: 20 }]; 

$(foo).animate({ x: "+=30" }, 1000, 
      function () { alert(this.x); });
```

Spits out "40" and "50".